# Unable to make POST request in Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create webservices in JAVA Spring boot with backend as SQL Server 2012. I followed the tutorial from this website https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/.

The only change i did was, changed the application.properties as

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=SampleSpringDB
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sqlpassword
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

Tomcat does not show any errors while running the app.

While testing POST method in Postman i get error in postman as

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-11-21T04:44:06.474+0000",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/api/notes/"
}
```

The code is totally copied from the above mentioned site.

Code for Controller

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value="/api", produces="application/json")

public class NoteController {

@Autowired
NoteRepository noteRepository;

// Create Note
@PostMapping("/notes")
public Note createNote(@Valid @RequestBody Note note) {
    return noteRepository.save(note);
}

// Get all notes
@GetMapping("/notes")
public List<Note> getAllNotes() {
    return noteRepository.findAll();
}

// Get Single Note
@GetMapping("/notes/{id}")
public Note getNoteById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long noteID) {
    return noteRepository.findById(noteID).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Note", "id", noteID));
}

// Update Note
@PutMapping("/notes/{id}")
public Note updateNote(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long noteID, @RequestBody Note noteDetails) {
    Note note = noteRepository.findById(noteID)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Note", "id", noteID));
    note.setTitle(noteDetails.getTitle());
    note.setContent(noteDetails.getContent());

    Note updatedNote = noteRepository.save(note);
    return (updatedNote);
}

// Delete Note
@DeleteMapping("/notes/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteNote(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long noteID) {
    Note note = noteRepository.findById(noteID)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Note", "id", noteID));
    noteRepository.delete(note);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

}

POSTMAN POST url

localhost:8080/api/notes/
body params as {"title":"test","content":"test"}

Comment: Please post your controller code and the URL which are hitting in postman.

Comment: Try: `localhost:8080/api/notes`. Removing trailing forward slash

Comment: This was the application.properties in that website                                 
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/notes_app?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root


## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

Comment: can you shate Note class?

Comment: localhost:8080/api/notes was also tested but got same error @JigneshM.Khatri

Comment: Can you please provide the log trace of tomcat when hitting this URL from postman.

Comment: @Kartik it is a valid url..see here https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-boot-mssqlserver/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties

Comment: There is no logs created while hitting the post url @JigneshM.Khatri

Comment: Then probably it is not reaching your project. What value is set on `contextPath`? I think you are missing `contextPath` from your URL in postman

Comment: Most probably `contextPath` should be your project name. Something like this - `http://localhost:8080/<contextPath>/api/notes`

Comment: localhost:8080/easy_notes/api/notes tried this also but same issue @JigneshM.Khatri

Comment: Add this in your application.properties - `server.servlet.contextPath=/easy_notes` and then try `localhost:8080/easy_notes/api/notes`. You need to restart tomcat after making these changes

Comment: added server.servlet.contextPath=/easy_notes. But same issue persists @JigneshM.Khatri

Comment: Is your tomcat running on 8080?

Comment: yes @JigneshM.Khatri.   Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/easy_notes'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed (In a Weird way) 
I created the same project with backend as MySQL and tested out the service. It worked fine. Then i added SQL server dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

into pom.xml and changed the application.properties to

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=SampleSpringDB
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto 
= create-drop
```

By doing so it worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a quick check whether you added `@SpringBootApplication`:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

@SpringBootApplication includes @ComponentScan which scans the package it's in and all children packages. Your controller may not be in any of them.

Comment: The below annotaions are there on the class
SpringBootApplication
EnableJpaAuditing
ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=NoteRepository.class)

Comment: remove `@ComponentScan` and check again and try to have all your classes in one package

Answer (score 0):

Did you added sqlserver connector at **pom.xml**? If added please skip this answer and I will remove this. I tested your code on mysql server its working fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i added <dependency>
 <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
             
  </dependency>    I did not try out your method. Will try it out and give an update